# Is there a SQL statement that lets me create exact duplicate of partitioned table structure in Oracle 12c?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I need to clone a partitioned table in Oracle (without data).
Is there a SQL statement that lets me do it in Oracle 12c?

I tried using DBMS metadata and then executing generated DDL.
Looking for something simpler I can use in PL/SQL or SQL code.

Answer (score 3):

Just figured it in 12c.
This creates exact copy with partitions (no data);

```
CREATE TABLE GES.TARGET_TABLE
  FOR EXCHANGE WITH TABLE GES.SOURCE_TABLE.
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, if you get the DDL from metadata, the partitioning will be handled by Oracle. See [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/18061/34876) on DBA SE site.

You might also perform an empty copy of the table

```
CREATE TABLE zxy AS SELECT * FROM xyz WHERE 1=2;
```

And then alter table adding the partition, if you want a "simpler" approach (yet longer)